# Extract numeric from an alphanumeric string

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array, and I'm trying to access an element at the loc1 + 4th index.

I get a type mismatch error.

```vb
Dim atype As Variant
Dim loc1 As Integer

atype = Worksheets("Inputs").Range("B21")

loc1 = InStr(atype, "Loan")
loanpct = atype(loc1 + 4)
```

My cell value is "Bond-61.87% Loan-38.13%", I want to extract "38.13%".

With the comment below, I understand that it is not an array. Should I try to convert the string to an array?

Comment: You don't have an array unfortunately. The value of a single cell is not an array.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner, this works! However when I added the Cdbl, I got a type mismatch error again, but it works fine without the CDBL. I understand its for data conversion, do I really need it here?

Comment: its String for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the string we use MID.  The string is not an array with items that can be referenced like an array.

```
Dim atype As String
Dim loc1 As Integer
Dim loanpct As Double

atype = Worksheets("Inputs").Range("B21")

loc1 = InStr(atype, "Loan")
loanpct = Application.Evaluate(Mid(atype, loc1 + 5))

Debug.Print loanpct
```

Now `loanpct` is a number and can be used in later code.

But this assumes that everything after `Loan-` can be converted to a number.  If there is any non numeric character after `Loan-` then it will fail.